# HTTP 500 response every second request

Tags: grails

I've implemented a custom authentication scheme using a filter that calls an `authenticate()` method on an `AuthService` in the before interceptor of all my Controllers. The `authenticate()` method uses `groovy.sql.Sql` and a [UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html) to attempt to connect to the database and then check to make sure that database user has the appropriate role. The database is Oracle and is part of a legacy ERP, so that is the only way I could do authentication.

The problem I'm experiencing occurs when I submit a request with invalid credentials. A SQLException containing an `"ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"` is thrown as is expected. My try/catch block catches and suppresses it, and the code proceeds correctly in denying the request. However, the next request always returns the SQLException in a 500 response regardless of the credentials supplied. Any ideas as to why that is and what I can do to fix it?

```
def authenticate(def username, def password) {
    def authorized = false
    Sql sql

    if (username != null && !username.equals('')) {
        try {
            dataSource.setCredentialsForCurrentThread(username, password)

            sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)
            def row = sql.firstRow("**SQL removed for privacy**")

            if (row != null && row.has_permission == 1) {
                authorized = true
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            sql.close() 
        }
    }

    return authorized
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any error in the code posted. The username and password come from where? Maybe there's the problem.

Comment: The username and password are being collected from the params map and passed in to the authenticate method. It seems to me that the framework is capturing the SQLException and saving it until the next request. I don't understand the underlying framework enough to know, though.

Comment: I think that dataSource is a singleton for the application, so in the first attempt to get the connection (by any place) after you setting this incorrect username and password will hit the invalid username and password. So when the exception occurs, you must back to the default username and password.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I don't think it quite works that way since the credentials are set per thread rather than overwriting the default, but your suggestion makes sense as a possible solution. I have noticed that the same thread tends to be used for requests from the same client.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot! Submit your recommendation as a full answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that dataSource is a singleton for the application, so in the first attempt to get the connection (by any place) after you setting this incorrect username and password will hit the invalid username and password.

So when the exception occurs, you must back to the default username and password.

Comment: This can be done by calling `dataSource.removeCredentialsFromCurrentThread()` in the catch block of the code above.